# Recaptcha in rails : verify_recaptcha returning always true in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, proxy, recaptcha

I integrated [Recaptcha gem](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) in my Rails 3.2 application. And everything works fine in my local box.

But when I deployed it in test server, captcha is shows in the page. But whatever value I enter for the captcha, `verify_recaptcha` function returns true for it. So all the value is geting accepted for the captcha.

**In development system it is working but in test system it is not working, can you tell me why this behavior?**

Answer (score 1):

I got the reason. I went through source code of recaptcha gem. In that `verify_recaptcha` function always return `true` if the environment is **`test`**.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove entries from `Recaptcha.configuration.skip_verify_env` to force reCAPTCHA usage in tests. I see that `test` and `cucumber` are in that Array by default.

```
Recaptcha.configuration.skip_verify_env.delete 'test'
```

worked for me.

Comment: Where do you put this?

Comment: One can place this in a variety of locations. I have it directly in the only system test class that references recaptcha in my app. One could also place it in a test helper (test_helper.rb, spec_helper.rb, rails_helper.rb, etc. depending on which testing framework you use) if more than one test interacts with recaptcha.